# Core Data migration fails, but what's happening?

Tags: core-data, core-data-migration

I try to migrate my Core Data Model with a mapping model. It seems to find the mapping model and actually get pretty far in the migration, but I'm not sure. However, in the end it fails with a generic error and I have no clue what is actually going wrong.

Am I missing the cause of the error in [the log](http://pastie.org/9133639), and if so, what is the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting validation failures. As you've probably figured out, Core Data

1. Figures out that it needs to migrate the persistent store
2. Finds an appropriate mapping model, `FourToFive.cdm`
3. Begins the migration

Later on it fails, though. The errors are not generic-- they're quite specific. They all look like this (wrapped for readability):

```
"Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed.
    (Cocoa error 1570.)\" UserInfo=0x10a747bb0 {NSValidationErrorKey=startDate,
    NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.),
    NSValidationErrorObject=<NSManagedObject: 0x10a7380f0> (entity: TimeEntry; id:
    0xd00000000008000e <x-coredata://FB4CCC6C-6EB7-44DB-A3F2-F64E23C64827/TimeEntry/p2> ;
    data: <fault>)}",
```

What this says is that

- You have a validation failure (because `NSValidationErrorKey` and `NSValidationErrorObject`)
- This error is on the `TimeEntry` entity
- The error is specifically caused by the `startDate` attribute.
- The validation error is `1570`, which is `NSValidationMissingMandatoryPropertyError` (see [Core Data Constants Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Miscellaneous/CoreData_Constants/Reference/reference.html) in the docs for this).

So: The new version of `TimeEntry` appears to have a non-optional attribute called `startDate`, but in exactly five cases you appear to be migrating a nil value for that attribute. Easy fixes for this would include making the attribute optional or setting a default value in the data model. But you can't add a mandatory attribute and not assign some value for it.

There's also a message about `Failed to delete support directory for store` that I don't completely understand. The fact that the migration proceeds after that message *suggests* that it's not your problem, and in any case your errors don't stem directly from that.

Comment: I interpreted the "The operation couldn't be completed" as the meaning of the code, that was a bit short-sighted. Thanks a lot for the explanation. The startDate value shouldn't be nil though, there's a FUNCTION() in the mapping to fill that field. I'll post a followup question about it.